# asp:textbox hour difference with Javascript "onchange"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need some help here, I have three `<asp:TextBox>` in my form and I need to calculate the time difference between 2 of them (and set the difference value on the third).

I have done it with PostBack and it's working fine, but I want to do it from client side (no PostBack needed). That's why I want to know if there is a way to make the calculation and show the value in the third TextBox with javascript.

Some times I will need to calculate the time difference between 2 different dates. But I can't set the "Date" inside the TextBox.

The Format I need is "HH:mm".

Could somebody help me with this?

### EDIT (Code addition):

ASPX:

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TBStart1" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TBEnd1" runat="server" Width="50px" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TBDuration1" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

C#:

```
if (IsPostBack)
        {
            //CHECK IF THE FIELD IS NOT BLANK. IF IT'S BLANK, THE PROCESS WILL NOT START.
            if (TBEnd1.Text != "")
            {
                DateTime veinticuatro1 = DateTime.ParseExact("23:59", "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DateTime unminuto1 = DateTime.ParseExact("00:01", "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DateTime inicio1;
                inicio1 = new DateTime();
                inicio1 = DateTime.ParseExact(TBStart1.Text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                DateTime fin1;
                fin1 = new DateTime();
                fin1 = DateTime.ParseExact(TBEnd1.Text, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                //CHECK IF THE END TIME IS LOWER THAN THE START TIME. THIS MEANS THAT THE INTERVAL IS BETWEEN TWO DIFFERENT DATES (EXAMPLE: 23:50 TO 01:30) 
                if (fin1 < inicio1)
                {
                    TimeSpan diferencia1 = fin1.Subtract(inicio1);
                    DateTime duracionveintitres1 = veinticuatro1.Add(diferencia1);
                    DateTime duracionfinal1 = duracionveintitres1.AddMinutes(1);
                    string dife1 = duracionfinal1.ToString("HH:mm");
                    TBDuration1.Text = dife1;
                    TBDuration1.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    TimeSpan diferencia1 = fin1.Subtract(inicio1);
                    DateTime diferenciadt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(diferencia1.ToString(), "HH:mm:ss", null);
                    string dife1 = diferenciadt1.ToString("HH:mm");
                    TBDuration1.Text = dife1;
                    TBDuration1.Focus();
                }
            }
```

Some of the field names are in Spanish (diferencia, duracionveintitres, etc). Sorry for that.

Comment: show your code. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution for this.

I had to change my `<asp.TextBox>` to `<input/>`. I found the script in this URL:
https://www.linuxito.com/programacion/483-como-restar-horas-en-javascript

### Here is the code:

SCRIPT:

```
        function HourDifference() {

        start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        end = document.getElementById("end").value;

        startMinutes = parseInt(start.substr(3, 2));
        startHours = parseInt(start.substr(0, 2));
        endMinutes = parseInt(end.substr(3, 2));
        endHours = parseInt(end.substr(0, 2));

        minutesDiff = endMinutes - startMinutes;
        hoursDiff = endHours - startHours;

        if (minutesDiff < 0) {
            hoursDiff --;
            minutesDiff = 60 + minutesDiff;
        }

        if (minutesDiff < 10) {
            minutesDiff = "0" + minutesDiff;
        }

        if (hoursDiff < 0) {
            hoursDiff = 24 + hoursDiff;
        }

        hours = hoursDiff.toString();
        minutes = minutesDiff.toString();

        if (hours.length < 2) {
            hours = "0" + hours;
        }

        if (minutes.length < 2) {
            minutes = minutes + "0";
        }

        document.getElementById("difference").value = hours + ":" + minutes;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<p><input type="text" id="start" value=""/></p>

<p><input type="text" id="end" value="" onchange="HourDifference();" /></p>

<p><input type="text" id="difference" value="" /></p>
```

This is working ok.

### Important:

The input format should be "HH:mm" (if 1:00 am, is 01:00; if 1:00 pm, is 13:00).

Answer (score 0):

it should be something similar to :

```
$('#TBEnd1').on('change',function() 
{
  var start_time = $('#TBStart1').val();
  var end_time = $('#TBEnd1').val();

  var diff =  new Date(end_time) - new Date( start_time);  



  $('#TBDuration1').val(diff);
}
```

Comment: this diff  variable is in millisec so you might need to divide by 1000 to get secs

Comment: And how should I implement it in the Textbox?

Comment: the last line "$('#TBDuration1').val(diff);" should assign the resulted deference to the result text box  "TBDuration1"

Comment: I've tried to set the script into the <head> in the Masterpage. Nothing changes. Should I set it into the aspx form? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

The below code will obtain a datetime in text format and find the difference in hours and minutes. I hope this will meet your requirements or at least push you on the right tracks.

HTML

```
<div id="textBoxOne">
2016-09-20 20:00:00
</div>
<div id="textBoxTwo">
2016-09-23 20:31:00
</div>
<div id="ShowTimeBetweenDates">

</div>
```

Javascript

```
var dateOne = document.getElementById("textBoxOne").innerHTML;
var dateTwo = document.getElementById("textBoxTwo").innerHTML;
var diff =  (new Date(dateOne) - new Date(dateTwo))
var totalHours = Math.floor(Math.abs(diff/ 3600 / 1000));
var totalMinutes = Math.abs(((diff % 86400000) % 3600000) / 60000); 
var showTimeDiff = document.getElementById("ShowTimeBetweenDates");
showTimeDiff.innerHTML = "Time Diff : " + totalHours + " : " + totalMinutes;
```

result

> 2016-09-20 20:00:00
>
> 2016-09-23 20:31:00
>
> Time Diff : 72 : 31

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/foch389k/)

**Recommendations**

Instead of parsing it like this and using a text box Jquery provides "jquery ui date parser" a simple way to obtain a date object, you can use a date picker with this. Check it out [found here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

hope this helps, best of luck

Comment: Wow thanks! I will check this tomorrow, and let you know if it works.

Comment: I've tried this with no success. I need to input the Start-end time every day, so I can't use a <div> with a specific value.