# set Different colors in asp:DropDownList Items

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an  in my form, with 4 different options (items)
What I need to do it's to set a different color from client side, without PostBack.

### Items:

- Select...       (white)
- Complete        (green)
- Running         (yellow)
- Waiting in SEV1 (red)

Could somebody help me with this?

### Edit (with Dropdown code)

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Select...</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Complete</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Running</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Waiting in SEV 1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>No Batch</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

I have only looked for a solution for this, with no success yet. That's why I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: what have you written so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This markup applies a different background color to each item, and sets the `onchange` event handler:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="SetDropDownListColor(this);">
    <asp:ListItem style="background-color: White !important;" >Select...</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="background-color: Green !important;" >Complete</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="background-color: Yellow !important;" >Running</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="background-color: Red !important;" >Waiting in SEV 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="background-color: Blue !important;" >No Batch</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The following Javascript ensures that the color of the selection box matches the color of the selected item:

```
function SetDropDownListColor(ddl) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
        if (ddl.options[i].selected) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'White';
                    return;

                case 1:
                    ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'Green';
                    return;

                case 2:
                    ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'Yellow';
                    return;

                case 3:
                    ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';
                    return;

                case 4:
                    ddl.style.backgroundColor = 'Blue';
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `!important` modifier is set in the markup of the items in the list, in order to override the background color set to the whole control in the Javascript function.

In order to preserve the color of the DropDownList after a postback, the following line of code can be added to the Javascript block. It defines a handler for the `load` event of the page, in which the color of the selected item is applied to the selection box:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { SetDropDownListColor(document.getElementById('<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>')); }, false);
```

Comment: This works!!!! Thank you so much, this is exactly what I want. 
Just one more question: If there's a postbax after the Item Selection in dropdown, the Item stays ok but without color. 
A way to "solve" this is to change the item and select it again. Is there a way to avoid this step?

Comment: Good! I updated the answer. The `load` event handler will restore the color of the selection box after a postback.

Comment: Oops, there was a typo in the last code sample (`DropDownList0` instead of `DropDownList1`). I corrected it.

Comment: Awesome ConnorsFan! this works 100% perfect!! I should send you a gift from Argentina now, this was a headache :D

Comment: You're welcome! For now, the best present you can give me is to upvote the answer. :-)

Comment: I cannot do it yet because I'm a new user in this forum and I haven't the needed "reputation". But when I'm able to do it I will do it obviously. 

By the way, I have another "question" created. I haven't receive a solution for that yet, could you please check at it? maybe you can help me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926624/asptextbox-hour-difference-with-javascript-onchange/36926883?noredirect=1#comment61415862_36926883

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me...

```
ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
listItem.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: Gold !important;");
listItem.Text = "Apply for funding";

dlPayment.Items.Add(listItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following code

In the filename.aspx.cs file...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        System.Drawing.Color c1 = new System.Drawing.Color();
        Type t = c1.GetType();
        int row;
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p1 in t.GetProperties())
        {
            ColorConverter d = new ColorConverter();
            try
            {

                DropDownList2.Items.Add(p1.Name);
                for (row = 0; row < DropDownList2.Items.Count - 1; row++)
                {
                    DropDownList2.Items[row].Attributes.Add("style",
                          "background-color:" + DropDownList2.Items[row].Value);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Catch exceptions here if needed
            }
        }
     }
}
```