# How to change color in DropDownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add different color to the items in the dropdown list,how can i do that?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Status"  runat="server"ForeColor="Gray" Font-Size="12pt" Font-Bold="True" Style="text-align: center;"
      Font-Names="arial" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource10" CssClass="form-control"
      DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource10" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DataEntryConnectionString %>"  
     SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [Status] ">      
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Do it with javascript.

Comment: `<asp:DropDownList>` does not support this functionality directly. You'll need to write a Control-Adapter to render the appropriate HTML (setting `style=""` on each `<option>` element). Unfortunately Microsoft designed and released WebForms in 2001 and hasn't changed it much since ASP.NET 2.0 in 2005 (ASP.NET MVC 1.0 came out in 2008) so it's very difficult to use modern web techniques in WebForms.

Comment: 3rd party controls. Xamarin, Infragistics, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [set Different colors in asp:DropDownList Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926663/set-different-colors-in-aspdropdownlist-items)